# Want to read file retrieved from database in the same format it was being saved in C# windowsForm

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I am using C# Windows Form application to insert a document file (word, pdf & text) in to SQL server database,The below code I used to convert the file into binary and after ward I upload this file in to database:

```
    FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(file);
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file);
    long byteSize = fileinfo.Length;
    FileStream myFileStreams = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(myFileStreams);
    byte[] fileStream = br.ReadBytes((int)byteSize);
```

The file is saved successfully but when I retrive it from database the file is not in a readable format the below code I used to retrieve from database and to save it on local disk:

```
    //the file is fetch by its id and is saved in DataTable dt1 on its row[0][1]
    byte[] cv = (byte[])dt1.Rows[0][1];
    string cvName = dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    string ext = dt1.Rows[0][2].ToString();

    //saved in bin
    string pathOfCv = "new\\" + cvName + ext;
    File.WriteAllBytes(pathOfCv, cv);
    File.Create(pathOfCv);
```

The retrieved file has unreadable text which I want to read in the same format I saved and I think there is a problem in conversion of the file may be I just can not directly write bytes array in the file.

Please give me some code example how can I resolve this problem thanks.

Comment: what is the column type in DB ? this is binary data and should be save like one ... MSSQL have `binary` column type

Comment: Why are you using a `BinaryReader` to read the data from the file when storing it?

Comment: the column type is varbinary(2000) in the db

Comment: I have also tried to do it without BinaryReader but no use

Comment: did you check that the file size is not > 2000 ?

Comment: Well one issue you've got is that `File.WriteAllBytes(pathOfCv, cv);` creates a new file at the given path, so your next line `File.Create(pathOfCv);` will do more harm than good.

Comment: yes the file is too small right now not more than 10Kb since I'm testing for now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using MemoryStream 
smth like:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cv);
FileStream file = new FileStream(cvName + ext, FileMode.Create,System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
byte[] bytes = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Read(bytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);
file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
file.Close();
ms.Close();
```